NSProgressIndicator bindings don't do anything
I'm trying to bind a NSProgressIndicator to Progress, but with the following code I only get an indeterminate progress indicator with a blue bar forever bouncing left and right, even after the two timers fire. According to the documentation:

Progress is indeterminate when the value of the totalUnitCount or completedUnitCount is less than zero or if both values are zero.
What am I doing wrong?

class ViewController: NSViewController {
    
    let progress = Progress()

    override func loadView() {
        view = NSView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 500, height: 500))
        let progressIndicator = NSProgressIndicator(frame: CGRect(x: 100, y: 100, width: 100, height: 100))
        progressIndicator.bind(.isIndeterminate, to: progress, withKeyPath: "isIndeterminate")
        progressIndicator.bind(.value, to: progress, withKeyPath: "completedUnitCount")
        progressIndicator.bind(.maxValue, to: progress, withKeyPath: "totalUnitCount")
        progressIndicator.startAnimation(nil)
        view.addSubview(progressIndicator)
        
        progress.completedUnitCount = 3
        progress.totalUnitCount = 10
        Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1, repeats: false) { _ in
            print(1)
            self.progress.completedUnitCount = 6
        }
        Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 6, repeats: false) { _ in
            print(2)
            self.progress.completedUnitCount = 0
            self.progress.totalUnitCount = 0
        }
    }

}


Please be careful as nsprogress updates are not delivered on main thread.

But the documentation says: "Each of the properties of a progress object, including totalUnitCount, completedUnitCount, and fractionCompleted, support key-value observing (KVO). This makes it extremely easy for a view or window controller object to observe the properties, and update UI elements, such as progress indicators, when the values change."

"notifications always being sent on thread which updates the property." => You can use it as long as you update NSProgress properties on the main thread.

Ok, but this applies to any object observed via KVO, not just Progress.

Cocoa Bindings use Objective-C and the name of the Objective-C property is indeterminate. Use the #keyPath string expression to get the correct key path.
progressIndicator.bind(.isIndeterminate, to: progress, withKeyPath: #keyPath(NSProgress.isIndeterminate))


Thanks, that seems to be an issue indeed. The problem now is that when the second timer fires, I would expect the progress indicator to become indeterminate, but instead it just shows a tiny static blue dot (probably equivalent to 0% progress). Do you have any idea why?

The animation stopped. Schedule startAnimation on the main thread to start it again.

Thanks, that works. Is there a way to do this without having to keep a reference to the NSProgressIndicator, i.e. only via Progress?

I don't think so. Usually a progress indicator doesn't become indeterminate later on.
